# Irradiance Map ( Irradiance environment map)?

Tags: opengl, shaders, rendering, lighting, global-illumination

As irradiance map is generated for every possible normal for all the texels in environment map (as every texel act as a light source) so that we can look up irradiance map, based on normal of fragment to find out its resulting illumination.

- When Irradiance map is generated, does it get generated for every object in the scene to capture all possible normal and then eventually combined in a single texture?
- Is there any example code to create irradiance map and use it to light the scene?
- Any one has an example of CG-shader for reading irradiance map?

Thanks

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=10e4fBz_ofU&index=52&list=PL09X4HXJpa8kfw8cZjyYZel8WlOT5B1_k

Comment: Irradiance maps are typically stored as a bunch of cube maps. Cubemaps can be generated on a grid, per object, or per world.